# CSS Auto top div

Tags: html, css

Need your help about simple css question :

How to auto top div using display: inline block and vertical-align: top with my case below?

The css here :

```
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 194px;
background: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
text-align: left;
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HX3k/)

Help much appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean by "auto top div"?

Comment: I want no white space, fit it exactly below

Comment: For this issue u should doing it in jquery. css only this limit.

Comment: Any example for that ?

Comment: Get rid of the `margin-top: 5px;`, replace it with `top: 0px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple columns:

```
<div class="content_wall_column">
    <div class="content_wall">...</div>
    <div class="content_wall">...</div>
</div>

<div class="content_wall_column">
    <div class="content_wall">...</div>
</div>
```

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/8HX3k/7/).

Comment: Like this answer, however i wonder how to do it without making colums. So css is not stricted with your html structure, thus can make infinite amount of coloms(if it fits in screen ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

change your  css for class content_wall like this

```
.content_wall
{
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 194px;
background: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
text-align: left;
}
```

Removed the margin and the padding;

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8HX3k/9/)

or even better
give the padding first then remove the top padding
 like this

```
.content_wall
{
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 194px;
background: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 10px;
padding-top:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
text-align: left;
 }
```

[Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8HX3k/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top: 5px` from `.content_wall`, but you probably don't want them to touch each other, so don't remove it, but change it to `margin-bottom: 5px`.

Then add following to your stylesheet:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Check [**the updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/8HX3k/15/)